# In Solr, can we take max score instead of sum for or clauses?

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm working on a Solr query that has 4 OR conditions with one AND condition:

```
(
    (
        {!dismax qf=respondent_address_txt mm=3<70% v=$q2}^3.0 
        OR 
        {!dismax qf=respondent_addresses_txt mm=3<70% v=$q2}^1.0 
        OR 
        {!dismax qf=respondent_address_txt mm=3<70% v=$q3}^3.0 
        OR 
        {!dismax qf=respondent_addresses_txt mm=3<70% v=$q3}^1.0 
    ) 
    AND  
    {!dismax qf=respondent_name_txt mm=2<70% v=$q1}^3.0
)
```

Is it possible that of for OR conditions score don't add up instead they should take max of them,

say 4 separate query parts results in scores 1,2,3,4, than instead of total score as 10 it should be 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, (e)dismax query parsers allows precisely to do that using the [`tie`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Thetie_TieBreaker_Parameter) parameter.

The default makes a "disjunction max query" already, so having the sum instead means this parameter may be overridden somewhere in your config or in the request (set to `1.0` instead of `0.0`).

> The tie parameter lets you control how much the final score of the
>   query will be influenced by the scores of the lower scoring fields
>   compared to the highest scoring field.
>
> - A value of "**0.0**" - the default - makes the query a pure "disjunction
>     max query": that is, only the maximum scoring subquery contributes to
>     the final score.
> - value of "**1.0**" makes the query a pure "disjunction sum query" where
>     it doesn’t matter what the maximum scoring sub query is, because the
>     final score will be the sum of the subquery scores. Typically a low
>     value, such as 0.1, is useful.